# Username gone from login screen

Tags: windows, login

I have a Lenovo X61 tablet that runs Windows.  It runs automatic updates weekly and after one of these updates, my user account was gone from my login screen.

Now, I can login as a guest or administrator but never as the user account I have been using.  When I go into My Computer\Users, my account is there, but I want it back as an option to login when I first turn on my computer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked Control Panel -> User Accounts to see if your account is still there?  (BTW, you should probably identify what version of Windows you're running.)

Comment: On the users Start --> Run --> compmgmt.msc
Go to local users and groups, users, double click your profile, verify the "Account is Disabled" is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy

Select Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options

Look for "Interactive logon: Do not display last user name"

> This security setting determines whether the name of the last user to log on to the computer is displayed in the Windows logon screen.
>
> If this policy is enabled, the name of the last user to successfully log on is not displayed in the Log On to Windows dialog box.
>
> If this policy is disabled, the name of the last user to log on is displayed.
>
> Default: Disabled.